# Required Img files for heimdall root

Tags: samsung, rooting, linux, heimdall

Folks, I'm trying to root a phone with Heimdall (on Linux).

Completed steps so far:

1. Downloaded Factory Firmware
2. patched it with Magisk
3. setup heimdall
4. downloaded PIT from phone
5. backed up phone with `adb backup -apk -shared -all -f <filepath>/backup.ab`
6. installed twrp recovery

So now I would go on and flash the patched images.
From the magisk patch and the firmware, i get those files:

```
boot.img
cache.img
cm.bin
hidden.img
modem.bin
param.bin
recovery.img
sboot.bin
system.img
userdata.img
```

Comparing this with the contents of my PIT, I am missing these files:

```
md5.img
efs.img
cpefs.img
m9kefs1.bin
m9kefs2.bin
m9kefs3.bin
carrier.img
tombstones.img
dnt.ssw
steady.bin
modem_debug.bin
nad_refer.bin
```

Some people only use recovery.img and cache.img, others use all of them, so now I'm confused. Hence my questions:

- What is the minimum set of files required to flash in order to root the phone?
- I.e. are the ones I have enough, respectively
- are the missing ones required?

Thank you big time!